# How can I reset the calendarchangeobserver in singlerowcalendar library?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-calendar

I'm using a library called [singlerowcalendar](https://github.com/miso01/SingleRowCalendar) in my app. My app contains a toggle button that will change the calendar mode form showing days of month to showing months of year.

[days of month view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcNzr.png)

[months of year view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oY1GR.png)

The thing is I'm including the calendar setup code in the toggle change listener, and as a consequence the app keeps piling up calendar selection change listeners, and now I get the calendar change callback to fire multiple times. 
Is there a way to keep only one calendar change listener and removing the others.

here is the code of the toggle button where I call setCalendar();

```
toggle.addOnButtonCheckedListener(new MaterialButtonToggleGroup.OnButtonCheckedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onButtonChecked(MaterialButtonToggleGroup group, int checkedId, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked && checkedId == R.id.btn_day) {
                selectedTimeFrame = "day";
                tvChartTitleDay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tvChartTitleMonth.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Log.d("pongo2", "day selecteeeeed");
            }
            if (isChecked && checkedId == R.id.btn_month) {
                selectedTimeFrame = "month";
                tvChartTitleDay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                tvChartTitleMonth.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Log.d("pongo2", "month selecteeeeed");
            }
            setCalendar();
        }
    });
```

Here is the calendar setup code.

```
private void setCalendar() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(new Date());
    ArrayList<Date> list = new ArrayList<>();

    if(selectedTimeFrame.equals("day")) {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH , -700);
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            list.add(calendar.getTime());
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH , -1);
        }
        tvMonth.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tvMonth.setText(DateUtils.INSTANCE.getMonth3LettersName(calendar.getTime()));
        tvYear.setText(DateUtils.INSTANCE.getYear(calendar.getTime()));
    } else {
        calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH , -24);
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            list.add(calendar.getTime());
            calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH , -1);
        }
        tvMonth.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tvYear.setText(DateUtils.INSTANCE.getYear(calendar.getTime()));
    }

    myCalendar.setDates(list);
    myCalendar.init();
    myCalendar.select(5);
}
```

calendar change observer is here:

```
 private void initCalendar() {
    myCalendarChangesObserver = new CalendarChangesObserver() {
        @Override
        public void whenWeekMonthYearChanged(String s, String s1, String s2, String s3, Date date) {

        }

        @Override
        public void whenSelectionChanged(boolean b, int i, Date date) {
            if (b) {
                tvMonth.setText(DateUtils.INSTANCE.getMonth3LettersName(date));
                tvYear.setText(DateUtils.INSTANCE.getYear(date));
                Log.d("pongo", date.toString());
                loadNewData();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void whenCalendarScrolled(int i, int i1) {

        }

        @Override
        public void whenSelectionRestored() {
        }

        @Override
        public void whenSelectionRefreshed() {
        }
    };

    myCalendar.setCalendarChangesObserver(myCalendarChangesObserver);
}
```